# Is there a way to stream via hardware from a PC to a laptop not in fullscreen?

Tags: video, hdmi, streaming

Basically I have a PC with 2 HDMI ports video card and I want to mirror my PC display image to a laptop, but I still want to be able to use this laptop.

I suppose the video stream should just run in a separate window, just like Teamviewer but through hardware. Is there a possible solution with my setup?

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is No, this isn't going to be possible.

First off, in order to even input a stream into a laptop. The laptop needs to have a video input. Which is very very rare. I've read that it does exist on certain laptops, but it's very uncommon. I'm going to go ahead and assume you don't have this sort of input. But there is a work around.

You're going to need to buy a USB to HDMI adapter. As far as which one to buy. That's up to you.

[image]

Now to address why the answer is NO. When you do connect one of your HDMI connections from the PC to the USB to HDMI adapter (laptop). According to the settings on your PC. You're only going to have the options to Extend or Mirror the PC's display. So trying to display a small window of the PC's output on your laptop isn't possible.

It would be possible using Teamviewer as you mentioned. From all the examples I've seen with USB to HDMI adapters. It displays only the full screen. I seriously doubt anyone that created the drivers/software for those adapters took into consideration someone would want to display both screens at once, like you're trying to do.

Edit Workaround: There are in fact high end pieces of hardware that do allow you to do this. These companies did create a piece of software themselves to in fact allow you to view your HDMI input source into a separate window.

Elgato Game Capture HD Capture and AVerMedia Live Gamer HD.

But It should be noted both of these pieces of hardware are quite expensive. I've also watched reviews claiming that the Elgato experiences a bigger delay than the Avermedia product. Also the intent on these products are meant for recording the stream you're capturing. But In your situation, I think it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and great explanation. I googled a bit more and found a streaming device called AverMedia Live Gamer Portable. If I'm correct it can work the way I need. It has HDMI input port and connects with usb to another computer, which can receive the video stream directly into OBS (streaming software). It should work, right?

Comment: Edited to reflect your findings.